# Sending JSON to Spring MVC controller

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to send JSON to a Spring MVC Controller. On the Spring MVC side, everything is configured correctly.

Below is the code but doesn't seem to run:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var frm = $("#myForm"); 
    var dat = frm.serialize(); 
    $.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST', 
    url: $('#myForm').attr('action'), 
    data: dat, 
    contentType: 'application/json' 
    success: function(hxr) { 
        alert("Success: " + xhr); 
    } 
}); 
});   
 </script>   
</head>
<body>
<h2>Application</h2>
<form id="myForm" action="/application/save" method="POST" accept="application/json" onclick="i()">
                <input type="text" name="name" value="myName">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In Tomcat I get the following error:

> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerE
>   xceptionResolver handleNoSuchRequestHandlingMethod
>   WARNING: No matching handler method found for servlet request: path '/application/save', method 'POST', parameters map['name' -> array['myName']]

Any ideas where I am going wrong? I am new to JSON. I am trying to to send JSON to Spring MVC controller.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/run/*")
public class HistoryController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "save", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"content-type=application/json"})
public @ResponseBody Response save(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception {
    Response userResponse = new Response();
    System.out.println("UserId :" + " " + user.getName());
    return userResponse;
}
}

@RequestMapping(value = "find", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Response find() {
    System.out.println("Run");
    Response userResponse = new Response();
    userResponse.setVersionNumber("1.0");
    return userResponse;
}
```

When invoking /application/run/save I get a JSON response. However the @RequestBody does not work.

---

I still have had no luck. Have read some many similiar problems. The requirement is that the server will only accept application/json types. I am using a Spring MVC Controller. As mentioned earlier, the code sends a response back as JSON through @ResponseBody. I want to get information through the @RequestBody in my Spring MVC Controller. I am using JSP to send JSON to Spring MVC Controller. My code and Spring MVC can be seen below:

I am new to JSON and Javascript.

JSP - index.jsp

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html"%>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) { 
    var frm = $("#myForm");
   var dat = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray()); 

$.ajax({ 
     type: 'POST', 
     url: $('#myForm').attr('action'), 
     data: dat,
     contentType: 'application/json',
     dataType: 'json',
     error: function() {
        alert('failure');
     }
     success: function(hxr) { 
         alert("Success: " + xhr); 
     }
  }); 
); 
}; 
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<h2>Application</h2>
<form id="myForm" action="/application/save" method="POST" accept="application/json" onclick="i()">
    <input type="text" name="userId" value="User">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When running this I am not getting any output. In the Chrome I get 404 Not found error and in Tomcat I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver     handleNoSuchRequestHandlingMethod
WARNING: No matching handler method found for servlet request: path '/application/sa
 ve', method 'POST', parameters map['userId' -> array<String>['User']]
```

Is something wrong here in the JSP part?

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5">

     <display-name>WebApp</display-name>

     <context-param>
        <!-- Specifies the list of Spring Configuration files in comma separated format.-->
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/service.xml</param-value>
     </context-param>

     <listener>
        <!-- Loads your Configuration Files-->
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
     </listener>

     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>

     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>

     <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
     </welcome-file-list>    
</web-app>
```

service.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.web"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean id="jacksonMessageChanger" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jacksonMessageChanger"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>-->

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <util:list id="beanList">
                <ref bean="jacksonMessageChanger"/>
            </util:list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>-->  
</beans>
```

Controller

```
package com.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import com.webchannel.domain.User;
import com.webchannel.domain.UserResponse;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/application/*")
public class SaveController {

@RequestMapping(value = "save", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"content-type=application/json"})
public @ResponseBody UserResponse save(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception {
    UserResponse userResponse = new UserResponse();
    System.out.println("UserId :" + " " + user.getUserId());
    return userResponse;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody UserResponse delete() {
    System.out.println("Delete");
    UserResponse userResponse = new UserResponse();
    userResponse.setSuccess(true);
    userResponse.setVersionNumber("1.0");
    return userResponse;
}
}
```

When invoking /application/delete I get JSON returned. So I know my JacksonProcessor is configured correctly. The problem is in @RequestBody.

Where am I going wrong? Please help me.

Comment: within your code you do not seem to be doing anything with created `dat`. Isn't it?

Comment: so should in my <form> tag should I have a parameter called <input type="name">?

Comment: Ok, I have modified. Please see above and let me know where I am going wrong. It still does not work.

Comment: Can you try replacing `$(function i() {` with `function i() {` and `});</script>` with `}</script>`?

Comment: I have tried this. It still does not work. Not sure what to do. I have added the following: type: 'POST',  
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/application/run',
      data: dat Basically the '' and commas

Comment: Why exactly do you want to send JSON? What's the concrete functional requirement? Does that Spring MVC controller only accept a request body in JSON format instead of the standard `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` like as standard forms and standard ajax requests send? Your concrete problem suggests that the Spring MVC controller doesn't accept a request body in JSON format at all. Just use `var dat = frm.serialize();` the usual way then.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit hard to follow since there seems to be a few different problems.

But looking just at this problem:

> In Tomcat I get the following error:
>
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerE xceptionResolver handleNoSuchRequestHandlingMethod WARNING: No matching handler method found for servlet request: path '/application/run', method 'POST', parameters map['name' -> array['myName']]

In the HTML you posted, you have a `<form>` that is set to `POST` to `/application/run`.

However, in your `@Controller` class, you do not have any method bound to this URL.

Because you've annotated the class with `@RequestMapping("/run/*")` and the method is annotated with `@RequestMapping("save")`, the `save()` method is actually bound to the URL `/run/save` - which is neither the URL you are sending data to with `$.ajax()` nor the URL the form is pointing at.

I would suggest turning up logging on the `org.springframework.web` loggers to `DEBUG` - when your app starts up Spring will log every URL that each method is mapped to.

Comment: sorry, it should be run/save but still same problem.

Comment: I don't think you need the `*` in the `@RequestMapping(/application/*)`. Did you take my suggestion to turn up logging to examine exactly which methods are bound to exactly which URLs?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need make couple of changes

1. Since your controller has `@RequestMapping("/run/*")`, you may need to change this to `@RequestMapping("/run/")` and in the jsp form action you may need to change `<form id="myForm" action="/application/run/save" method="POST" accept="application/json" onclick="i()">`, since you have defined `@RequestMapping(value = "save", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"content-type=application/json"})` for the 'save` method in the controller.
2. You may need to define the @RequestParam in the save method in controller like `public @ResponseBody Response save(@RequestParam(required=true, value="name") String name, @RequestBody User user) throws Exception {...}`

Since it clearly says that there is no handler attached to the request you are submitting.

Comment: Ok, please see edited code. I have also tried RequestMapping("/run/") but still same error. I actually do not want to fetch from RequestParam. I want the JSON to be deserialized through the RequestBody

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var frm = $("#myForm");
    var dat = frm.serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $('#myForm').attr('action'),
        data: dat,
        contentType: 'application/json'
        success: function(hxr) {
            alert("Success: " + hxr);
        }
    });
});    
</script>   
</head>
<body>
<h2>Application</h2>
<form id="myForm" action="/application/run" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="myName">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>​
```

The `dataType:'json'` is specifying what the format you are expecting from the server,

And it would be better to assist if you post your handler code.

Comment: Please note the `hxr` typo (which is after all also a misnamed variable by the way, it does not represent the `XMLHttpRequest` object at all).

Comment: yep, thanks @BalusC, it will be the data returned from the server.

Comment: still it does not work. Please see above changes. BalusC is the requirement is that the server only accepts and sends JSON. I can send JSON but can't receive. I would like to receive in @RequestBody. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method in the controller mapped to your `/application/run`. I'm not sure which one you want to call, but to the `url` you have to add `find` or`save`. Or create a method mapped to `/application/run`. Cheers!